# Problemas con la conexión a internet desde android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permisos

Estoy intentando crear una app CRUD contra una base de datos en la nube, pero no me deja acceder a internet, aunque tiene los permisos....
Alguna idea de que le puede pasar??
He comprobado si la app se conecta, y me dice que no esta conectado a internet

Comprobación de el estado de la red

```
public void compruebaInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni =cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Estas conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No estas conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Activación de los permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Alguna idea de que puede pasar??

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Jorgsys, pero mis dudas no iban tanto por el método que comprueba la conexión a internet, si no al hecho de no estar conectado a internet cuando la aplicación tiene los permisos.
Te agradezco la aclaración de la clase NetWorkInfo. Pero el problema en sí... Por que no puedo conectarme a internet???

Comment: El problema como indico en mi respuesta es que estás usando el método isConnectedOrConnecting lo cual es incorrecto debes usar if (ni != null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected())

Comment: Visto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el problema es en esta linea:

```
if (ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
```

Debes revisar si `NetworkInfo`  es diferente de `null` pero también si la conexión esta disponible (`isAvailable()`) y es posible una conexión a la red (`isConnected()`) , por lo tanto debes usar:

```
  if (ni != null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected()){
```

---

Pero es importante comentar que el uso de la clase `NetWorkInfo` y sus métodos es obsoleto, ahora se debe hace uso de la clase `ConectivityManager` y métodos `getNetworkCapabilities()` o de la clase `NetworkCapabilities`, por lo que puedes hacer uso de este método:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    //NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    //NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    //NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;    
}
```

y llamar el método anterior desde tu método de esta forma:

```
public void compruebaInternet(){
    if (isOnline(this)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Estas conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No estas conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Jorgsys, pero mis dudas no iban tanto por el método que comprueba la conexión a internet, si no al hecho de no estar conectado a internet cuando la aplicación tiene los permisos.